# I was trying to do video conferencing with webRTC. This works within the local network but fails on different network

Tags: javascript, ssl, webrtc

I have tried with the SSL to connect on the different network, but when ever the offer is created it takes the public ip (of the caller) as local ip 127.0.0.1. Thus moving forward fails to connect to other peer.
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_security.htm].

```
callBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
console.log("Intiating the Call") 
var callToUsername = callToUsernameInput.value;
 //console.log("Intiate", yourConn)
if (callToUsername.length > 0) {
  connectedUser = callToUsername;
    
  // create an offer 
  yourConn.createOffer(function (offer) { 
     send({ 
        type: "offer", 
        offer: offer 
     }); 
     console.log("Setting local description")
     yourConn.setLocalDescription(offer); 
     console.log(offer)
        
     }, function (error) { 
     alert("Error when creating an offer"); 
    });  
   } 
  })
```

[Picking local address instead of public address while creating offer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLbdC.png)

How do i solve this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set STUN and/or TURN servers in the webrtc parameters. This allows you to connect cross network.

Comment: I am already using google stun server to get the public of my machine but for some reason whenever i try to call other peer the offer that is created uses local ip by default. Thanks @ Drik V